# Modelling an amphitheater/hemicyclic rows

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry, curve-modifier

I'm quite new to Blender, I started using it for a project which requires me to 3D-model a theatre. Up until now, I've somewhat managed to do what I wanted thanks to online tutorials, but now I'm facing a problem for which I found no solution/tutorial/help on the internet. The problem is : how can I model a hemicyclic fly of rows (such as in antique amphitheaters) ?
Something like this (I don't own this pic) :
[image]

I've tried to model a single row, make it follow a curve/path, and then use an array modifier to reproduce it, but the result is not correct, as it's just a bunch of steps with a fixed curvature - not following the radius augmentation of a (hemi)circle.
I guess I need to use a circle mesh and somehow model the steps along it, but I can't seem to find the proper way to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...
Thanks for your attention !

BONUS (lol) : it's actually even more complicated that this technically, because the theatre I'm modelling has curved side walls as well. And the stairs inbetween rows follow this same curve. I don't even know if this is do-able at all.
Here's a very ugly sketch to represent the room's layout :
[image]

Comment: You could try it with the Simple Deform modifier and its Bend mode but I'm not sure it will fit your need (not sure to understand your drawing). Anyway you can try with whatever method then apply the modifiers and finish it manually

Comment: i think this could be done via GN so you would have a lot of flexibility. But...of course...you need to have some knowledge of GN to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "dirty" GN solution, which - hopefully - some GN pro's will improve.

But i think it is a good starting point and maybe you can use already some ideas of this.

[image]

and by the way: my first community wiki answer - so i will not receive any reputation from this...and all other won't too. But i hope some guys will nevertheless have fun helping here ;)

[image]

[image]

feel free to download, change and upload better version of my "dirty" blend file

[image]

Comment: Woooow, thank you for your time ! I'm not familiar with GN, but I guess I'll give it a shot and learn ! It looks... quite powerful. My other concern now (as below) is with the placement of the small steps, as here, they are rectilinear, but in my original theatre (I work with plans of a real place), the stairs are curved (as in my ugly sketch which is probably not very helpful lol).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try with a *Simple Deform (Bend* mode), it would work with a *Curve* modifier as well. If it doesn't fit your needs please precise in what way:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time ! I thought that was the solution I had tried, but mine did not look as neat; I'll give it another shot. My problem now with this option is the placement of the stairs (small ones) : here, the stairs are rectilinear. I need them to follow a curve (as in my ugly sketch). I tried doing a separate object and bending it in other axes, but it did not give the proper result, because I need to curve not each step, but the stairs as a whole - if that makes sense. Maybe I can try and figure that out by placing the small steps along a Bezier Curve or something ?